# What is the cause of Stackoverlow exception on the CWnd::DefWindowProc of a control

Tags: c++, mfc, stack-overflow

I had a strange problem in an MFC Application that took a lot of time to solve and was hard to detect for me, It was a stackoverflow on the CWnd::DefWindowProc method it was called recursively that happened just for custom button on a specific dialog, that button worked fine on other dialogs.

Comment: Um, this is not a question.

Comment: @RaymondChen: I changed the title.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Later I discovered the problem, the control was **subclassed twice** in different controls that was a real bug caused by me.

I'm emulating the way of OWL for creating child controls in the MFC, when a user create an instance of control class in the constructor then there is no need to go to the **DoDataExchange** to call the **DDX_Control**  that is done in the base dialog it iterates over a list of children to call this for them and after the window had got a handle then we will call it's **SetupWindow()** method it is like the OnLoad on the .NET C#, also a nice thing is that I check first to see if the parent has an item with that ID using **GetDlgItem** if there is a control on the dialog with this item then it is a resource control and need DDX_Control else if it wasn't on the dialog then it is a dynamic control and I call CreateWindowEx with it's previously saved attributes in Attr member.

That way missed another check and that what caused the *stackoverflow* in that dialog the programmer created 2 buttons with the same ID [he was depending on the ID for icon drawing and both was used in same job but for different grid controls on same dialog], the user captured there button click using message map inside the button class and called the appropriate routine for that,  ...any way when the first one was about to be created it's id was not on the dialog so it was created dynamically, when the second one with the same id we searched the dialog for that ID and yes it was found so it treated it as a resource control and called DDX_Control then it was subclassed twice by that caused a stackoverflow, to fix that, I stored a pointer to the control as property of the window with a special name and when an id is found on the dialog then get it's HWND if it has that property then it is created previously and I need to create a new dynamic one else then it is not created yet.

- what I wanted to say don't use DDX_Control for a previously
  subclassed control in MFC.

I hope that this text is readable, I posted this question with the answer to help anyone has this problem to find answer, I suffered a lot from it.